# Initialize attributes object class and makes it const

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create read only attribute.
The example below works well, and it is inspired and simplified from https://howto.lintel.in/how-to-create-read-only-attributes-and-restrict-setting-attribute-values-on-object-in-python/

```
class Attr1(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = int(value)
class Attr2(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        self.value = int(value)
class AttrFormula(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.attr1 / instance.attr2
class Class(object):
    attr1 = Attr1()
    attr2 = Attr2()
    attrFormula = AttrFormula()

A = Class()
A.attr1 = 1
A.attr2 = 2
print("Class A attr1 =", A.attr1)
print("Class A attr2 =", A.attr2)
print("Class A attrFormula =", A.attrFormula)
B = Class()
B.attr1 = 3
B.attr2 = 3
print("Class B attr1 =", B.attr1)
print("Class B attr2 =", B.attr2)
print("Class B attrFormula =", B.attrFormula)
```

And outputs this:

```
Class A attr1 = 1
Class A attr2 = 2
Class A attrFormula = 0.5
Class B attr1 = 3
Class B attr2 = 3
Class B attrFormula = 1
```

But now, i want to change

```
A = Class()
A.attr1 = 1
A.attr2 = 2
```

by

```
A = Class(1,2)
```

because i want to disable all setter attributes and make the attributes unmodifiable. Something desired like that :

```
class Attr1(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        raise AttributeError("You can't change attr1")
class Attr2(object):
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return self.value
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        raise AttributeError("You can't change attr2")
class AttrFormula(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return instance.attr1 / instance.attr2
class Class(object):
    attr1 = Attr1()
    attr2 = Attr2()
    attrFormula = AttrFormula()

    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        self.attr1 = attr1              # ERROR because it calls __set__
        self.attr2 = attr2

A = Class(1,2)
print("Class A attr1 =", A.attr1)
print("Class A attr2 =", A.attr2)
print("Class A attrFormula =", A.attrFormula)
B = Class(5,7)
print("Class B attr1 =", B.attr1)
print("Class B attr2 =", B.attr2)
print("Class B attrFormula =", B.attrFormula)

B.attr1 = 10 # Forbidden, desired error
```

How to init `attr1` and `attr2` in `Class` ?

Comment: You want read-only attributes, so you've used a code snippet that... doesn't actually create read-only attributes? (Also you're storing data on the descriptor object instead of the instance, which is going to lead to all instances sharing the same attribute values.)

Comment: I guess `attrFormula` is read-only, but it's still a really verbose and buggy way to implement what `property` would do much easier.

Comment: Why not use [`attrs`](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html#immutability) or [`dataclasses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#frozen-instances)?